# Cannot boot ubuntu

Tags: boot

I got a used desktop. It looks like a gaming setup with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX graphics card and Ripjaws memory.

When I try to start it up, all I see is 5 red dots or squares. Sometimes it says Ubuntu. I cannot access GRUB. I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu with a USB as well as Windows 10 with a USB. It seems like I cannot use the mouse or keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different Ubuntu image and check what the boot order is set to. You might see windows boot manager in there, select that to have it boot to windows - then use Rufus to write the ISO.  I suspect a problem with the installation media

Comment: what do you mean try a different Ubuntu image? you mean a different version iso?

Comment: I tried booting again from a different Ubuntu iso but nothing has changed. It still just shows 5 red dots with squares around them. I cannot access any info from the desktop like boot order or boot manager.